# $(pwd) equivalent on windows in node run script

Tags: node.js, windows

I use the following on my linux machine in node.js in my `package.json` under the scripts object:

```
"dev": "NODE_ENV=development NODE_PATH=\"$(pwd)\" browser-refresh --nolazy --inspect=9229 application/index.js",
```

I know `cd` is the windows equivalent of `pwd`, but I don't know how to get it into the node.js run script. I'm not used to window command line at all.

Comment: isn't it cd? like %cd%?

Answer (score 0):

Weird but this works after trying for so long:

```
"dev_w": "cmd.exe /C \"set NODE_ENV=development && set NODE_PATH=.&& browser-refresh --nolazy --inspect=9229 application/index.js\""
```